# What does this selector mean a.listen("parsley:field:validated",this,this.reflow)?

Tags: javascript, css, parsley

I'm trying to understand how the `Parsley.js` works and in the code I've found these selector:

`a.listen("parsley:field:validated",this,this.reflow)`

Does somebody know what could it mean if the css selectors and elements are divided by colons? These are not pseudo classes or elements, aren't they?

Thank you!